# Using string.Format with unicode information

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, character-encoding, escaping

I am attempting to use string.Format to include a currency symbol and seeing an unexpected result.

See the following:

```
var textToReplace = "Final price is {0} {1}";
var output = string.Format(textToReplace, "Include MAD currency symbol here", "123.90");
output.Dump();
```

// Currency symbol is د.م.

```
Final price is د.م. 123.90
```

Strangely as I type this question, the SO question area automatically switch the currency symbol position with amount. Its bit hard to explain, try it yourself.

I would like to see the currency symbol followed by the amount. However I see the the amount followed by the currency symbol.

How can I explain this behaviour?

Comment: *How can I explain this behaviour?* symbol is RTL, so in fact it's before the price

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that the symbol is RTL. The position is correct, but it gets rendered in the other way. You could try to add the Unicode [`\u200E`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200e/index.htm).
This will mark that the character should be Left-to-Right

for example:

```
var textToReplace = "Final price is {0} {1}";
var output = string.Format(textToReplace, "Include MAD currency symbol here\u200E", "123.90");
output.Dump();
```

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zVegfA